# Are there any statistics or research on location approval by users on mobile and desktop browsers?

Tags: mobile, browser, statistics, location

I'm looking for statistics or research about users that permit browsers to use their location, drilled down to the type of browser, platform, vs. native apps, etc.

Also, general recommendations about UX statistics and research resources worth following would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely interesting question and one that I have been unable to find any answer to.

However, I was able to easily find the following links that may (by reading between the lines) yield some insight:

Google's guidelines for developers considering the use of location in their apps https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/device-access/user-location/user-consent?hl=en

Apple's guidelines on how reviewers will treat an application using location.
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#location

An article about public reaction to location tracking
http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2012/02/im-being-followed-how-google-151-and-104-other-companies-151-are-tracking-me-on-the-web/253758/

I know this is not a direct answer but I hope it goes someway to helping you find one.